# angular sticky table box shadows

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

So I have a sticky table but I only need the box shadow on the second column which is Requestor Name on the right side , I want to remove that shadow I put arrow on the screenshow below because both first and second column are sticky and also the last column is sticky but it looks bad then the Requestor Name column has both boxshadow on left and right.

How do we do that ? Thanks.

[image: table]

#html code

```
 <table
                          mat-table
                          [dataSource]="dataSource"
                          matMultiSort
                          (matSortChange)="requestsListTable.onSortEvent()"                        >

                        <ng-container matColumnDef="requestTitle" sticky>
                          <th mat-multi-sort-header="requestTitle" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Request Title</th>
                          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                            <div class="checkbox-container td-value-name">
                              <mat-checkbox [checked]="selectedWorkFlowIds.includes(element.workflowApprovalId)" [disabled]="!isAllowedBulkUpdate(element)" class="no-navigation" color="primary" (change)="onChangeSelect(element, $event, 'request')"></mat-checkbox> 
                              <div [matTooltip]="element.requestTitle" class="td-value-name">{{ element.requestTitle?.length > 45 ? element.requestTitle.slice(0,45) + '...' : element.requestTitle }}</div>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </ng-container>

                        <ng-container matColumnDef="requestorName">
                          <th mat-multi-sort-header="requestorName" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Requestor Name</th>
                          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                            <div class="td-value-name">
                              {{element.requestorName}}
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </ng-container>

                        <ng-container matColumnDef="requestTypeName">
                          <th mat-multi-sort-header="requestTypeName"  mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Request Type</th>
                          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
                            <div class="td-value-name">
                              {{element.requestTypeName }}
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </ng-container>

                        <ng-container matColumnDef="department">
                          <th mat-multi-sort-header="department" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Department</th>
                          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
                            <div class="td-value-name">
                              {{element.departmentName}}
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </ng-container>

                          <ng-container matColumnDef="requestorPriority">
                            <th mat-multi-sort-header="requestorPriority" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Requestor Priority</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
                              <div class="td-value-name">
                                {{element.requestorPriorityString}}
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </ng-container>
                  
                          <ng-container matColumnDef="projectTeamPriority">
                            <th mat-multi-sort-header="projectTeamPriority" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Project Team Data</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                              <div class="td-value-name">
                                {{element.projectTeamPriority}}
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </ng-container>
                  
                          <ng-container matColumnDef="requestDate">
                            <th mat-multi-sort-header="requestDate" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Request Date</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                              <div class="td-value-name">
                                {{element.requestDate | date : 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </ng-container>
                  
                          <ng-container matColumnDef="targetCompletionDate">
                            <th mat-multi-sort-header="targetCompletionDate" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Target Completion Date</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                              <div class="td-value-name">
                                {{element.targetCompletionDate | date : 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </ng-container>
                          <ng-container matColumnDef="currentStepName">
                            <th mat-multi-sort-header="currentStepName" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Current Step Name</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="align-icon-and-value">
                              <div class="td-value-name current-step-container">
                                <button mat-button (click)="onViewWorkflow($event, element)">
                                  <mat-icon style="padding-right: 10px;">remove_red_eye</mat-icon> {{element.currentStepName}}
                                </button>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </ng-container>
                          <ng-container matColumnDef="currentApprover">
                            <th mat-multi-sort-header="currentApprover" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Current Approver</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                              <div class="td-value-name" [matTooltip]="element.currentApproverName">
                                {{ element.currentApproverName?.length > 45 ? element.currentApproverName.slice(0,45) + '...' : element.currentApproverName }}
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </ng-container>
                          <ng-container matColumnDef="lastStepCompleted">
                            <th mat-multi-sort-header="lastStepCompleted" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                              Last Step Completed
                            </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                              <div class="td-value-name">
                                {{ element.lastStepCompleted }}
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </ng-container>

                          <ng-container matColumnDef="onHold">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="text-center">On Hold</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                              <div class="text-center">
                                <!-- <mat-icon class="dragCursor" (mousedown)="dragDisabled = false;"
                                  style="color: rgb(146, 146, 146)">drag_indicator</mat-icon> -->
                                <mat-checkbox [disabled]="!isProjectTeamData" class="no-navigation" color="primary"(change)="onChangeSelect(element, $event, 'OnHold')"
                                [checked]="element.isOnHold"></mat-checkbox>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </ng-container>
                      
                          <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
                            <th mat-multi-sort-header="status" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                              <div>
                                {{ element.statusDisplayString }}
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </ng-container>

                          <ng-container matColumnDef="actions" stickyEnd > 
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="text-center">Actions</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="text-center">
                              <div class="action-value-name">
                                <div style="display: flex">
                                  <div (click)="approve($event,element)" *ngIf="element.approveButton && isActionAllowed(element)" class="action-item with-divider text-center">
                                    <mat-icon style="color: #65B741;">check</mat-icon>{{element.approveButton}}
                                  </div>  
                                  <div (click)="reject($event,element)" *ngIf="element.rejectButton && isActionAllowed(element)" class="action-item">
                                    <mat-icon style="color: #DF2E38;">close</mat-icon>{{element.rejectButton}}
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </ng-container>
                         
                          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsTableLeft"></tr>
                          <tr mat-row (click)="viewDetails($event, row)" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsTableLeft"></tr>
                        </table>
```

#css snippet

```
.text-center {
    text-align: center
}

.cursor-pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sort-button {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.search-approval {
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: -2px;
}

.center-message {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.no-record {
    margin-top: -60px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.checkbox-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.mat-checkbox {
    margin-right: 10px;
    /* Adjust the margin as needed */
}

/* .mat-column-requestorName {
    position: sticky;
    left: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: inherit;
} */

/* 
.mat-table-sticky-border-elem-right {
    border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.mat-table-sticky-border-elem-left {
    border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

th.mat-column-actions,
td.mat-column-actions {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

th.mat-column-requestTypeName,
td.mat-column-requestTypeName {
    padding-left: 12px;
}

th.mat-column-requestTitle,
td.mat-column-requestTitle {
    padding-right: 12px;
}

th.mat-column-requestorName,
td.mat-column-requestorName {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
 */

th.mat-column-actions,
td.mat-column-actions {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.mat-column-requestorName {
    position: sticky;
    left: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: inherit;
    /* border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0; */

}

.mat-column-requestTitle     {
    background-color: inherit;
    /* border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0; */

}

th.mat-column-requestorName,
td.mat-column-requestorName {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

th.mat-column-requestTypeName,
td.mat-column-requestTypeName {
    padding-left: 12px;
}
```

Comment: what about my answer didnt it help you?

Comment: it works Sir but I combined it with the answer of the other guys and now the sticky works but my new problem is the problem above.

Comment: could you provide a sample data source or a stackblitz for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through the CSS, we need to specify upto which index you need to shadow to be displayed, that will help you understand how it works, we use `nth-child(2)` to select the second child `th` or `td`, and we can use `:last-child` to select the last `th` or `td`, this will enable the shadows!

```
.shaded-table thead tr > th:nth-child(2) {
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 3px #aaaaaa;
}

.shaded-table tbody tr > td:nth-child(2) {
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 3px #aaaaaa;
}

.shaded-table thead tr > th:last-child {
  box-shadow: -2px 0px 3px #aaa;
}

.shaded-table tbody tr > td:last-child {
  box-shadow: -2px 0px 3px #aaa;
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dytr9x-l73pb3?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sticky-columns-example.html,src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sticky-columns-example.ts)